# How can I parse arguments in a shell function and then make a multiline commit with it?

Tags: git, shell, sh, git-commit, git-squash

I'm following the [conventional commits](https://conventionalcommits.org/) standard and I want to make a shell function to do a *squash and merge* and commit changes with a parsed message, improving my coding speed and my commits consistency.

**My problem is** to parse the arguments and then use the result in the commit message.

- My actual code:

  ```
  function git_merge_squash() {
    git merge --squash "$1"
    shift
    msg= echo $'\n'"$*" | tr . \\n | tr - ' '
    # echo $msg
    git commit -m $msg
  }

  alias gmrs=git_merge_squash
  ```
- Usage example:

  ```
  $ gmrs f/my_branch Features.- Signup.-- Save hashed password
  asynchronously.-- Retrieve token.- Login.-- Retrieve token.-
  Logout.-- Destroy token
  ```
- Expected result:

  ```
  git merge --squash f/my_branch
  git commit -m "
  Features
    Signup
      Save hashed password asynchronously
      Retrieve token
    Login
      Retrieve token
    Logout
      Destroy token"
  ```

As you can guess, in my actual code my commented `echo` prints exactly the message that I want. But `git commit -m` command takes `$msg` as a string. I tried multiple other options, like simulating a file input with the `-F` flag, but I couldn't work it out.

How can I achieve my goal? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need to add `\n` as well in the commit message if it is mult-line.

Comment: `git commit -m "$msg"` (with quotes surrounding the msg var)?

Comment: Those solutions didn't work, thank you anyways.

Comment: While the resource you're touting has certain grains of good practices listed, squash-merging is not one of them: is basically destroys all the history led to the final shape of the branch merged, and makes `git bisect` useless.

Comment: An idea to use squash-merges often comes from mere incapability to use Git properly—for instance from being scared by "odd-looking history" stemming from multiple true merges. This can be easily dealt with by merely learning how Git branching works; [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-the-creators-of-git-do-branches-e6fcc57270fb) is one very good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I worked it out. I hope someone can get help from this.

- Working code

  ```
  function git_merge_squash() {
    git merge --squash "$1"
    shift
    git commit -m "$(echo $'\n'"$*" | tr . \\n | tr - ' ')"
  }
  alias gmrs=git_merge_squash
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to invent your own encoding for newlines; just use a second argument formatted the way you want.

```
git_merge_squash() {
  git merge --squash "$1"
  git commit -m "$2"
}

gmrs f/my_branch "\
Features
  Signup
    Save hashed password asynchronously
    Retrieve token
  Login
    Retrieve token
  Logout
    Destroy token"
```

Comment: The main reason why a don't use that is because it is easier to make mistakes and also because the " isn't fast to write (I need 2 keys, at least on my Spanish keyboard) and typing ".- " is much faster than what I replaced with it. Thank you

Comment: You have one pair of double quotes, and multiple newlines.